# Create a function that inherits from EventEmitter

Tags: node.js, typescript, prototype, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

Using TypeScript, is there a way to declare a function (not a class) that inherits from EventEmitter?

Using vanilla JS this is possible, but not sure how to do it with TS.

```
export const foo = function extends EventEmitter(){   // lol no

    return {}; // (I need to return something here)
};
```

here is how you implement it with JS (last time I checked):

```
const p = Object.assign(Object.create(Function.prototype), EventEmitter.prototype);

Object.setPrototypeOf(foo, p);
```

If I try doing it with TS, I get this problem/error:

[image]

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish in TypeScript?  functions don't really inherit from other functions so it's really not clear what you're trying to accomplish.  In plain JS, a constructor function can be made to extend another constructor function which there is already regular TypeScript syntax for (class inheriting from another class).  Why don't you just use that?

Comment: export class Foo extends EventEmitter {}.  Classes are functions

Comment: @generalhenry the Node.js champion - Foo is then a constructor under your scheme, I actually need to return some thing from foo. I updated the question.

Comment: I posted an answer, I think using classes here is cowardly and anti-social

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this correctly and to get TypeScript to play nice, we create a helper function that has the right signature:

```
import EventEmitter = NodeJS.EventEmitter;

export interface FunctionEmitter extends Function, EventEmitter {
}

export const makeFunctionEmitter = function (fn: Function): FunctionEmitter {

  const p = Object.assign(Object.create(Function.prototype), EventEmitter.prototype);
  Object.setPrototypeOf(fn, p);
  EventEmitter.call(fn);
  return fn as FunctionEmitter;

};
```

then we just use it like so:

```
export interface MyActualType extends FunctionEmitter{
  (a: string, b: boolean, c: number): X
}

export const myFuncEmitter = makeFunctionEmitter(<MyActualType >function(a,b,c){

   return X;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to manually mutate the function into something else then you need to also manually cast it :)

```
import { EventEmitter } from "events";
function target(emitter: EventEmitter){
  emitter.on('foo', ()=>{})
  console.log(emitter.on);
}
let f = function f(){}
const casted = Object.assign(f.prototype, EventEmitter.prototype) as EventEmitter
target(casted);
```